# Performance Considerations Using Multiple Layers of Generators in Python?

Tags: python, performance, generator

Are there any performance considerations for using a lot of generators chained together, as opposed to just a single generator.

For example:

```
def A(self, items):
    for item in self.AB(items):
        if object.A():
            yield item

def AB(self, items):
    for object in self.ABC(objects):
        if object.A() or object.B():
            yield object

def ABC(self, objects):
    for object in objects:
        if object.A() or object.B() or object.C():
            yield object
```

Clearly calling `A(objects)` is going to go through three different generators, but in many situations it makes the code re-use better if there are different generators to handle different filtering. Can anyone indicate that there is a significant impact on performance using this technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with chaining generators, but in this example there is no reason for A to call self.AB, it can just loop over items to get the same result.

You should write your code as clearly as you can and if it's slow then use a profiler to determine where the bottleneck is. Contrived examples such as this one are too far from reality to be useful indicators of performance.

Comment: Agree: A call to a generator is just a function call (even if it might seem a little more complex. The amount of time processing the calls should be very small indeed. 

It's basically the same as lambda x: lambda x: lambda x:x